# unable to plot using boxplot due to "object 'variable' not found"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to plot some data using standard graphics of R and ggplot2. First I have a DF with 15 column. So I decide to using the `reshape` package and to `melt` the data. I use this code.

```
require(reshape)
melta <- melt(alc, id.vars = c("SERIAL"))
boxplot(alc = melta,  variable~value)
```

But I stumble on this error

> "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found".

Where I made a mistake?

The structure of melta is.

```
'data.frame':   17108 obs. of  3 variables:
$ SERIAL: int  38029154 38043671 38090011 38092911 38096206 38097725 38098892 38098895 38098986 38099056 ...
$ variable: Factor w/ 14 levels "ALL_CATEGORIES_TOTAL",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ value   : num  662866 1404542 889061 1203516 736608 ...
```

NULL

Comment: What's the structure (`str(melta)`)?

Comment: Hm. Shouldn’t it be `boxplot(variable ~ value, data = melta)`, or, rather, (given your data structure) `boxplot(value ~ variable, data = melta)`?

Comment: Maybe i should convert serial from int to num?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
boxplot(data = melta,  value~variable)
```

Whit ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(melta, aes(factor(variable), value))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(variable))) +
   facet_wrap( ~ variable, scale="free")+ labs(title = "EC region")+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to add a heading of this plot `library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(melt_ec, aes(factor(variable), value), main = "EC region") 
p + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap( ~ variable, scale="free")`

Comment: Hi I add a title but how to add colour to my box plot. `library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(melt_ec, aes(factor(variable), value), main = "EC region") 
p + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap( ~ variable, scale = "free") + ggtitle("EC Region")
`